# jquery random rotate

Tags: jquery, rotation

I have a div with a bunch of images (20) and i like a little rotation on some let say +-2dg

i have try that with no success... all image are rotated equally

```
/* By default, we tilt all our images -2 degrees */
#gallery2 img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    }

/* Rotate all even images 2 degrees */
#gallery2 img:nth-child(even) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    }

/* Don't rotate every third image, but offset its position */
#gallery2 img:nth-child(3n)  {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    }

/* Rotate every fifth image by 5 degrees and offset it */
#gallery2 img:nth-child(5n) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
    }
```

So i like to have to code in jquery that will go through all the image in the div and random rotate it + ou - 2 dg

anybody know hot to do that ?

Comment: Does the CSS not rotate the images correctly? If it does then you don't need to post the styles, but rather the javascript your're having trouble with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#gallery2 img").each( function() {
  var rNum = (Math.random()*4)-2;  
  $(this).css( {   
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'2deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'2deg)'  
  } );  
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

i have try that.. work well but your code is better and shorter

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#gallery2 img").each( function() {
    var posneg = Math.floor( (Math.random() * 2)  );
    if (posneg == 0) {posneg=-1} else {posneg=1};
    var angle = Math.floor( (Math.random() * 5) * posneg );
    $(this).css( 'transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)' );   
    $(this).css( '-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)' );   
    $(this).css( '-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)' );
    $(this).css( '-o-transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)' );
    alert(angle);

    }); 
    }); 
</script>
```